# INTERNET_OPTION_ENABLE_HTTP_PROTOCOL / windows 10 gives strange results

Tags: http, delphi, http2, wininet, winhttp

I am trying to implement support for HTTP_PROTOCOL_FLAG_HTTP2

i.e. if the webserver supports it - my crawler should as well

```
      if (vosWin__EG__Win10 in msGetOS_Version.Version_Set) then
        begin
          vHttpProtocolSupport :=
             $00 // http 1.1 and older always on
          or $02 // http 2
          ;
          InternetSetOption(hHttpOpen_Request, INTERNET_OPTION_ENABLE_HTTP_PROTOCOL, Pointer(@vHttpProtocolSupport), SizeOf(vHttpProtocolSupport));
        end
      ;
```

However - if I use his flag - the GET content streams returned are all garbled - does not appear to use any encoding I can decode at least. Removing the flag again makes everything work.

Is there something I am missing in documentation about behavior of this flag?

...

From [WinHTTP over HTTP/2 with multiplexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59943931/winhttp-over-http-2-with-multiplexing) it would seem WinInet/WinHTTP does not implement full HTTP/2 multiplexing.

From https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/27400 it would seem if using HTTP/2 one should only use one connection at a time due the nature of HTTP/2

My crawler is built around using multiple connections. That said, it would be nice to leave it to the user using a single connection and then implement *as much as possible* of the HTTP/2 support in my usage of the WinInet/WinHTTP API.

i.e. request/response header decompression/compression... Is there more? (I would probably have to adjust code to check which HTTP mode we are running in.)

Comment: [Headers are compressed](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7540#section-4.3). Sounds like WinINet doesn't do the decompression work for you (cannot verify, no Windows 10 by hand).

Comment: [HTTP/2](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/2) is *semantically* similar to HTTP, but it is *technically* very different. Headers are compressed, data is framed, multiplexing, etc

Comment: Hi - I will try make some changes and report back. Ideally I would like to support http/2 over time with WinInet. Thank you both

Comment: [According to the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385328.aspx), `HTTP_PROTOCOL_FLAG_HTTP2` is supported in "Windows 10, version 1507 and later".

Comment: @Remy, now thinking of it, there should be some kind of API stability. I mean, I would expect that WinINet should be able to decompress headers for you, or what happens if you query by `HttpQueryInfo`? So as for data I would expect the same API stability, or am I wrong?

Comment: @Victoria i think maybe decompressing headers is the least of the worries. Seems the other things Remy mention are more complicated if one has to implement support for those things ourselves. But I will follow this SO

Comment: @Tom, my last point was about the API in general. I'm thinking about how the WinINet API will behave in case of reading headers and data. Should not WinINet do all the hard work for you to keep API compatibility with other HTTP protocol versions?

Comment: I have added a bounty this question as there must be some with more information.